# Include table name in SQL syntax that counts unique values

Tags: sql, qgis

The following SQL looks for duplicate unique ID's in my data so that I can clean it up. I would like it to include a list of the tables that the number exists in.

So

```
SELECT 
    GID_New, TableName, COUNT(*) no_matches
FROM 
    (SELECT GID_New 
     FROM "Drainage_Lines" AS TableName  
     UNION ALL
     SELECT GID_New  
     FROM "Drainage_Points" AS TableName    
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT GID_New 
     FROM "Drainage_Gross_Pollutant_Traps" AS TableName) t  
GROUP BY
    GID_New   
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query produces:

[image]

But I would like it to get this result:

```
GID_New | Table Name                      | no_matches 
--------+---------------------------------+-----------
Null    | Drainage_Points, Drainage_Lines |    19
1906    | Drainage_Points                 |     2
```

etc...

So then I can see that there's Null(s) in 2 tables but 1906 is only repeated twice in the Points dataset.

How can I do this? This is using QGIS flavour of SQL that only allows [these commands](https://sqlite.org/lang.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using flags:

```
SELECT GID_New, TableName, count(*) as no_matches,
       sum(is_dl), sum(is_dgp), sum(is_dgpt)
FROM (select GID_New, 1 as is_dl, 0 as is_dgp, 0 as is_dgpt
      from "Drainage_Lines" as TableName
      union all
      select GID_New, 0, 1, 0
      from "Drainage_Points" as TableName
      union all
      select GID_New, 0, 0, 1
      from "Drainage_Gross_Pollutant_Traps" as TableName
     ) t  
Group by GID_New
having count(*) > 1;
```

It is not exactly the format you want, but it has the same information.

Comment: Brilliant -works better as it actually gives the number of repeats in each dateset. There were a couple of typos in the code and it works fine once they are fixed.